Prefect Doesn't Terminate Completed Flows in Windows
I came across the following situation:
When prefect finishes a task, it continues to run in the windows server task manager.
E.g.:
The change name flow ended with full status, but it is still running and consuming memory in the windows task manager.
@flow(log_prints=True)
def change_name(name: str, new_name: str):
    name = new_name
    return new_name

